# A possible way to remove BigQuery column

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking around for an approach to update an existing BigQuery table.

With the [CLI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#createtablequery) I'm able to copy the table to a new one. And now, i'm looking for an effective to remove/rename a column.

It's said that is not possible to remove a column . So is it possible when copying table1 to table2 to exclude some columns ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by running a query that copies the old table to the new one. You should specify `allowLargeResults:true` and `flattenSchema:false`. The former allows you to have query results larger than 128MB, the latter prevents repeated fields from being flattened in the result.

You can write the results to the same table as the source table, but use the `writeDisposition:WRITE_TRUNCATE`. This will atomically overwrite the table with the results. However, if you'd like to test out the query first, you always could write the results to a temporary table first, then copy the temporary table over the old table when you're happy with it (using `WRITE_TRUNCATE` to atomically replace the table).

(Note, the flags I'm describing here are their names in the underling API, but they have analogues in both the query options in the Web UI and the bq CLI).

For example, if you have a table t1 with schema {a, b, c, d} and you want to drop field c, and rename b to b2 you can run

```
SELECT a, b as b2, d FROM t1
```

Comment: Thanks ! it's sound good :) The challenging fact now is to generate the query from the updated JSON schema file (nested and repeated fields). Indeed each schema is versioned and when a new version is created an update job will be fired in order to update all table with the old version.

Comment: We're doing this using the WebUI, but the created table is loosing its 'REQUIRED' on fields (they all become NULLABLE). Any ideas how to keep the REQUIRED on the table?